# Capturing every change in the clipboard python

Tags: python, winapi

How do I print each change in the clipboard using python win32api or ctypes in an infinite loop?

I tried using this:

```
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

def getClipboard(user32, kernel32):

   while 1:
       user32.OpenClipboard(0)
       if user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(1):
           data = user32.GetClipboardData(1)
           data_locked = kernel32.GlobalLock(data)
           clipText = ctypes.c_char_p(data_locked)
           kernel32.GlobalUnlock(data_locked)
           text = clipText.value
       else:
           text = ""
       user32.CloseClipboard()

       print text

getClipboard(user32, kernel32)
```

But it does not work

Comment: Hi @HelpMePlease, what does it mean it does't work? Does it run without error but the behavior is not the one you expect? Does it gives you an error? If yes can you then post it?

Comment: No error but it no print the clipboard content live

Comment: Could it be that you do not pass the `if user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(1)`? Then you'd only print an empty string...

Comment: DO NOT poll the clipboard in a loop like this. The correct way to monitor for changes in real time is to use `AddClipboardFormatListener()` (Vista+) or `SetClipboardViewer()` (pre-Vista) instead

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code works fine as it is. 
Please explain your problem.

One more thing if you ever need to watch for changes in the clipboard use [**AddClipboardFormatListener**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener) API. 
Of-course you will have to use something like *PumpWaitingMessages* & *PumpMessages* to get the Windows Message when something actually changes in the clipboard.